# Interpolating yearly to quarterly Data linearly - error

Tags: python, r, time-series, interpolation, frequency

I have yearly time series data for a number of countries I want to interpolate linearly to make them quarterly, either using R or Python. What has been discussed so far on stackoverflow does'nt answer my question.

I've been following the well-documented procedure by Jason Brownlee, i.e.:
https://machinelearningmastery.com/resample-interpolate-time-series-data-python/

For me case it looks like this:

```
YEAR CH  FR   US
2005 200 700  500
2006 300 740  530
2007 450 760  600
```

Code-wise I rewrote the blog's example for my needs:

```
def parser(x):
    return datetime.strptime('2005' + x, '%Y')

data = read_csv('data.csv', sep=';', header=0, parse_dates=[0], index_col=0, squeeze=True, date_parser = parser)
```

I get a long error message:

ValueError: unconverted data remains: +x

1)If I do not add the `+x` to the parser definition, all years are the same each observation. What is wrong about the parser?

2)Any ideas on how to treat multiple time series (i.e. CH, FR, US) at the same time?
I don't wanna tear my data set apart just for this preparational step.

3)If anyone has suggestions on how to do this in R I'd be super happy, all the procedures out there seem to be long and not getting me what I really need.

Comment: Why is this tagged `r`?

Comment: "either using R or Python"

Comment: Questions not focused on a single language are normally closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following base R solution uses `approxfun` to create an interpolating function and the calls it with the years and quarters. The interpolation method is the default `method = "linear"`.

```
year_qtr <- function(x, years){
  f <- approxfun(years, x)
  n <- length(years)
  qtrs <- unlist(lapply(years[-n], function(y) y + (0:3)/4))
  qtrs <- c(qtrs, years[n])
  list(x = qtrs, y = f(qtrs))
}

year_qtr(df1$CH, df1$YEAR)
#$x
#[1] 2005.00 2005.25 2005.50 2005.75 2006.00 2006.25 2006.50
#[8] 2006.75 2007.00
#
#$y
#[1] 200.0 225.0 250.0 275.0 300.0 337.5 375.0 412.5 450.0
```

**Data**

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "
YEAR CH  FR   US
2005 200 700  500
2006 300 740  530
2007 450 760  600
", header = TRUE)
```